# Using ssh-agent in windows git bash - Connection timed out

Tags: windows, ssh, git, ssh-keys

I'm trying to use ssh-agent in Windows git bash. I do

```
eval `ssh-agent`
```

it prints process PID, in task manager I can see that it indeed is running.
Then I do `ssh-add -l`. It thinks for some time and says: `Error connecting to agent: Connection timed out.`
I checked that environment variable `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` in current terminal is set to something, I checked that only one ssh-agent is running.

My firewall shows me that ssh-add connects to localhost (port number is different every time) but no bytes are sent or received. Surely I tried turning firewall off with no success.

My googling skills are failing me, all errors I could find were related to incorrect running of ssh-agent (i.e. without eval). I'm out of ides.

The question is: how do I make it work?

UPD: I booted in safe mode with networking and ssh-add works. So it must be something in my system setup.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I guess you are right; I did the edit.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue occurred several years ago and OP notes they do not know the reason the problem went away.

Comment: @music2myear no objections from OP :)

Answer (score 0):

You did add a key that was registered on your server, right?

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/keyname
```

then `ssh-add -l` will actually show something and you can ssh in:

```
ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Comment: It was quite a while ago, so I can't really tell now, sorry. But since it started working in safe mode I assume that the key was correct.